# How to get the increment value for the variable in a column using hive

Tags: sql, hiveql

I have columns like below

```
Annot Patient
X     100
X     100
N     100
N     100
S     100
S     100
V     100
N     100
N     100
S     100
```

I'm expecting output like below

I need the "X" value to be "0" always and all other variable groups should increment from 1,2,3,...

```
Annot Patient segment
N     100     1
N     100     1
X     100     0
X     100     0
S     100     2
S     100     2
V     100     3
N     100     4
N     100     4
S     100     5
```

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Do you have a column that specifies the ordering?

Comment: Yes, please take a look at the sample of the actual data below.

time sample # MLII MLII_adc V V_adc Annotation Patient
00:00.000 0 -0.145 995 -0.065 1011 X 100
00:00.003 1 -0.145 995 -0.065 1011 X 100
00:00.006 2 -0.145 995 -0.065 1011 X 100
00:00.008 3 -0.145 995 -0.065 1011 X 100
00:00.011 4 -0.145 995 -0.065 1011 X 100
00:00.014 5 -0.145 995 -0.065 1011 N 100
00:00.017 6 -0.145 995 -0.065 1011 N 100
00:00.019 7 -0.145 995 -0.065 1011 N 100

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dense_rank()` and `case` logic:

```
select t.*,
       (case when annot = 'X' then 0
             else dense_rank() over (partition by patient, (case when annot = 'X' then 'X' end) order by annot
        end) as segment
from t;
```

Comment: I used `dense_rank()` but it replaces the same value for the repeated groups.
But I want the increment value for the same repeated groups as well.

Like below
Annot Patient segment
N     100     1
N     100     1
X     100     0
X     100     0
S     100     2
S     100     2
V     100     3
N     100     4
N     100     4
S     100     5